# Trouble initializing Google RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClient

Tags: php, composer-php, recaptcha, autoload, google-cloud-repository

I am trying to add reCAPCHA to my website. Following the README.md from https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-recaptcha-enterprise, I have used composer to install google/cloud-recaptcha-enterprise on my server:

```
cd includes
composer require google/cloud-recaptcha-enterprise
cd ..
```

Then created a simple test.php

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

require 'includes/vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Cloud\RecaptchaEnterprise\V1\Key;
use Google\Cloud\RecaptchaEnterprise\V1\RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClient;
use Google\Cloud\RecaptchaEnterprise\V1\WebKeySettings;
use Google\Cloud\RecaptchaEnterprise\V1\WebKeySettings\IntegrationType;


$client = new RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClient();

echo "DONE";
?>
```

But I get a "HTTP ERROR 500" page not working. No warning, no error report. I have looked through the autoloader.php and the paths it generated are correct. I have checked with some other packages I have installed in my includes/ dir and the autoloader works fine with those.

I have tried composer2+PHP8.2 and composer1+PHP7.4.

I have tried not installing to my includes folder.

Trying to debug the autoloader a little, I modified my test.php:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$autoloader = require 'includes/vendor/autoload.php';
print_r($autoloader);
echo "</br></br>";
$results = $autoloader->findFile("Google\Cloud\RecaptchaEnterprise\V1\RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClient");
print "Found file for class at: $results</br></br>";

echo $autoloader->loadClass("Google\Cloud\RecaptchaEnterprise\V1\RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClient");

use Google\Cloud\RecaptchaEnterprise\V1\Key;
use Google\Cloud\RecaptchaEnterprise\V1\RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClient;
use Google\Cloud\RecaptchaEnterprise\V1\WebKeySettings;
use Google\Cloud\RecaptchaEnterprise\V1\WebKeySettings\IntegrationType;


$client =  new RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClient();

echo "DONE";
?>
```

and I get the following output:

```
Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader Object ( [vendorDir:Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader:private] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor [prefixLengthsPsr4:Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader:private] => Array ( [P] => Array ( [Psr\Http\Message\] => 17 [Psr\Http\Client\] => 16 [Psr\Cache\] => 10 [PHPMailer\PHPMailer\] => 20 ) [G] => Array ( [GuzzleHttp\Psr7\] => 16 [GuzzleHttp\Promise\] => 19 [GuzzleHttp\] => 11 [Grpc\Gcp\] => 9 [Grpc\] => 5 [Google\Type\] => 12 [Google\Rpc\] => 11 [Google\Protobuf\] => 16 [Google\LongRunning\] => 19 [Google\Iam\] => 11 [Google\Cloud\RecaptchaEnterprise\] => 33 [Google\Cloud\] => 13 [Google\Auth\] => 12 [Google\Api\] => 11 [Google\ApiCore\LongRunning\] => 27 [Google\ApiCore\] => 15 [GPBMetadata\Google\Type\] => 24 [GPBMetadata\Google\Rpc\] => 23 [GPBMetadata\Google\Protobuf\] => 28 [GPBMetadata\Google\Longrunning\] => 31 [GPBMetadata\Google\Logging\] => 27 [GPBMetadata\Google\Iam\] => 23 [GPBMetadata\Google\Cloud\Recaptchaenterprise\] => 45 [GPBMetadata\Google\Cloud\] => 25 [GPBMetadata\Google\Api\] => 23 [GPBMetadata\ApiCore\] => 20 ) [F] => Array ( [Firebase\JWT\] => 13 ) ) [prefixDirsPsr4:Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader:private] => Array ( [Psr\Http\Message\] => Array ( [0] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../psr/http-message/src [1] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../psr/http-factory/src ) [Psr\Http\Client\] => Array ( [0] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../psr/http-client/src ) [Psr\Cache\] => Array ( [0] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../psr/cache/src ) [PHPMailer\PHPMailer\] => Array ( [0] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../PHPMailer ) [GuzzleHttp\Psr7\] => Array ( [0] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../guzzlehttp/psr7/src ) [GuzzleHttp\Promise\] => Array ( [0] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../guzzlehttp/promises/src ) [GuzzleHttp\] => Array ( [0] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../guzzlehttp/guzzle/src ) [Grpc\Gcp\] => Array ( [0] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../google/grpc-gcp/src ) [Grpc\] => Array ( [0] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../grpc/grpc/src/lib ) [Google\Type\] => Array ( [0] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../google/common-protos/src/Type ) [Google\Rpc\] => Array ( [0] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../google/common-protos/src/Rpc ) [Google\Protobuf\] => Array ( [0] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf ) [Google\LongRunning\] => Array ( [0] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../google/longrunning/src/LongRunning ) [Google\Iam\] => Array ( [0] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../google/common-protos/src/Iam ) [Google\Cloud\RecaptchaEnterprise\] => Array ( [0] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../google/cloud-recaptcha-enterprise/src ) [Google\Cloud\] => Array ( [0] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../google/common-protos/src/Cloud ) [Google\Auth\] => Array ( [0] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../google/auth/src ) [Google\Api\] => Array ( [0] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../google/common-protos/src/Api ) [Google\ApiCore\LongRunning\] => Array ( [0] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../google/longrunning/src/ApiCore/LongRunning ) [Google\ApiCore\] => Array ( [0] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../google/gax/src ) [GPBMetadata\Google\Type\] => Array ( [0] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../google/common-protos/metadata/Type ) [GPBMetadata\Google\Rpc\] => Array ( [0] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../google/common-protos/metadata/Rpc ) [GPBMetadata\Google\Protobuf\] => Array ( [0] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../google/protobuf/src/GPBMetadata/Google/Protobuf ) [GPBMetadata\Google\Longrunning\] => Array ( [0] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../google/longrunning/metadata/Longrunning ) [GPBMetadata\Google\Logging\] => Array ( [0] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../google/common-protos/metadata/Logging ) [GPBMetadata\Google\Iam\] => Array ( [0] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../google/common-protos/metadata/Iam ) [GPBMetadata\Google\Cloud\Recaptchaenterprise\] => Array ( [0] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../google/cloud-recaptcha-enterprise/metadata ) [GPBMetadata\Google\Cloud\] => Array ( [0] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../google/common-protos/metadata/Cloud ) [GPBMetadata\Google\Api\] => Array ( [0] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../google/common-protos/metadata/Api ) [GPBMetadata\ApiCore\] => Array ( [0] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../google/gax/metadata/ApiCore ) [Firebase\JWT\] => Array ( [0] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../firebase/php-jwt/src ) ) [fallbackDirsPsr4:Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader:private] => Array ( ) [prefixesPsr0:Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader:private] => Array ( ) [fallbackDirsPsr0:Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader:private] => Array ( ) [useIncludePath:Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader:private] => [classMap:Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader:private] => Array ( [Composer\InstalledVersions] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../composer/InstalledVersions.php [GPBMetadata\GrpcGcp] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../google/grpc-gcp/src/generated/GPBMetadata/GrpcGcp.php [Grpc\Gcp\AffinityConfig] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../google/grpc-gcp/src/generated/Grpc/Gcp/AffinityConfig.php [Grpc\Gcp\AffinityConfig_Command] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../google/grpc-gcp/src/generated/Grpc/Gcp/AffinityConfig_Command.php [Grpc\Gcp\ApiConfig] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../google/grpc-gcp/src/generated/Grpc/Gcp/ApiConfig.php [Grpc\Gcp\ChannelPoolConfig] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../google/grpc-gcp/src/generated/Grpc/Gcp/ChannelPoolConfig.php [Grpc\Gcp\MethodConfig] => /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../google/grpc-gcp/src/generated/Grpc/Gcp/MethodConfig.php ) [classMapAuthoritative:Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader:private] => [missingClasses:Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader:private] => Array ( ) [apcuPrefix:Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader:private] => )

Found file for class at: /home/<user>/domains/<domain>/public_html/includes/vendor/composer/../google/cloud-recaptcha-enterprise/src/V1/RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClient.php

1
```

So the autoloader is finding the files, but the namespaces are not correct? The script still does not complete the "DONE" step and the class is not created.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: "But I get a "HTTP ERROR 500" page not working." - can you share the full and exact error message you are facing? Maybe it's written to your server's error log? Also, how is this problem related to recaptcha itself?

Comment: Maybe I'm way off in the weeds, but from my understanding the reCAPTCHA Enterprise flow is: 1) Have client generate a token via js call to google 2) send token to server 3) server creates assessment to validate token and legitimacy of client.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why my script was not displaying the thrown exception, but debugging a little more via putting echos into the google classes I found this exception:

```
Your default credentials were not found. To set up Application Default Credentials, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/external/set-up-adc
```

So yeah, creating a credential key file and setting an envirmental variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIAL solved the current issue.